# typedoc include not exported functions not work

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I use TypeDoc version 0.24.8, Node.js v20.2.0, TypeScript 5.0.4.
I try document not exported functions with typedoc-plugin-not-exported, but not work yet.

My typedoc.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://typedoc.org/schema.json",
    "entryPoints": ["src/index.ts"],
    "out": "doc",
    "plugin": ["typedoc-plugin-not-exported"]
}
```

My typescript source:

```
/**
 * Run a query on SQLite3 database
 * 
 * @param dbase Database used run query
 * @param sql The SQL command for run
 * @param params The SQL parameters
 * @returns Promise for executed query
 */
export function runQuery(dbase: Database, sql: string, params: Array<void>) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        return dbase.all(sql, params, (err: any, res: any) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err.message);
            }
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Prepare a statement on SQLite3 database
 * 
 * @param stmt Prepared statement for execute
 * @param params Parameters for statement
 * @returns Promise for executed statement
 */
export function execStatement(stmt: Statement, params: (string | number)[]): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        stmt.run(params, (err: any, res: any) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err.message);
            }
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Finalize a statement and commit executed SQLs 
 * @notExported
 * @param db Database for commit
 * @param stmt Statement to finalize
 * @returns Promise for finalizing and commit
 */
async function finalizeAndCommit(db: Database, stmt: Statement): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            stmt.finalize();
            await runQuery(db, "COMMIT", []);
            resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}
```

But only exported functions included in docs.

How can I make document for not exported functions?
What is the best practice in typescript generate source documentation?

Please help me. Thanx.